# How to update data from json using spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman

I created a table from an object called "Person", and I am able to post, delete and put from Postman. I have no problem with how to create a new query from JSON I type in postman. But, whenever I try to delete or update(using put) my query, I select the query I want by using @PathVariable and update the selected data by using @RequestVariable. But I want to be able to delete or update from JSON file. Here is how my code looks like.

Person object

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "person_sequence",
            sequenceName = "person_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "person_sequence"
    )
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
}
//Getters, Setters, Constructors and ToString is here
```

PersonController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/person")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }
    //@GetMapping
    //@PostMapping

    @DeleteMapping(path = "{personId}")
    public void deletePerson(@PathVariable("personId") Long personId{
        personService.deletePerson(personId);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "{personId}")
    public void updatePerson(@PathVariable("personId") Long personId,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String lastname){
        personService.updatePersonService(personId, name, lastname);
    }
}
```

This is my PersonRepository Interface

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

I am quite new to Spring Boot. It would be nice if I could get a code for this in @PutMapping and @DeleteMapping also how the code will look like in request in PersonService class.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to replace your RequestParams with "json content", right?
if so, you can use this:

```
@Valid @RequestBody final Person person
```

btw, leave your delete method as it is, using id of entity in delete should be enough, having there request body is not necessary

P.S. I'd create 1 new entity PersonDTO and use it for controller/service components and renamed your Person to PersonDAO and use that only for repository component

Comment: I do have a @Service class. I did not add it since I wanted to how it would be implemented. Sorry, I am quite new to springboot.

Comment: no worries, it was just a suggestion - to have separate entities for different layers of your app

Answer (score 0):

It's not often the case to use the delete method with the request body, instead, you can use the put method. Also, it's good practice to create separate (Dto) objects intended for JSON serializaiton.

```
@PutMapping()
public void deletePerson(@RequestBody PersonDto person){
    personService.deletePerson(person.getId());
}
```

Also, you can use the request body if you want to create or update entities.

```
@PutMapping(path = "{personId}")
public void updatePerson(@PathVariable("personId") Long personId, @RequestBody PersonDto person){
    personService.updatePersonService(personId, person);
}
```